# WebRTC Peer to Server Connection

Tags: node.js, typescript, webrtc

I've tried implementing a peer to server connection with WebRTC, unfortunately node-webrtc doesn't provide typescript types, which makes it really hard to add collaborators, and messes up the codebase.
Is there any other way to make a client to server connection using NodeJS and WebRTC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! Check out [werift-webrtc](https://github.com/shinyoshiaki/werift-webrtc) it is a typescript implementation of WebRTC for node.js

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so instead of using typescript, I've started building my own webrtc broadcadting media server using the native code I found here: https://webrtc.googlesource.com/src/

I also took inspiration from the way Discord created their servers, I found this information on this blog post: https://blog.discord.com/how-discord-handles-two-and-half-million-concurrent-voice-users-using-webrtc-ce01c3187429

I still havent't figured out a way how am I supposed to do this, what I think we have to do is to create a RTC Peer Connection using the `api/` directory in the native code, or something like that.

The answer above me, that I've marked as accepted, is useful if you want to go through the nodejs typescript way, I'll try figuring something out and keep you guys updated.

Comment: If Google's WebRTC implementation is too complex to integrate, you might also want to have a look at [libdatachannel](https://github.com/paullouisageneau/libdatachannel).